# rails, peridodic_call_remote, update form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have a form saved every 10 seconds or so, or maybe onchange. I'm using rails and have tried observe_fields and periodic_remote_call, but I don't know how to send a full full parameter with periodic and how to send a full form with observer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice post here: http://www.elevatedcode.com/articles/2006/12/20/using-observe_form/

Answer (score 0):

[`observe_form`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html#M001655) seems to be your solution. Read the documentation for the parameters (so it does what you want, since it seems not very clear yet) and it will send updates upon changes or timed periods to your controller.

Also add an action method to the controller which processes the information send to it, by storing it somewhere.